# Issue with subfolder in codeignitor. Not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I need some help. I am trying to access a page inside my subfolder in /public_html/app/Views/pages/views/  but its giving me error. 404 - File Not Found

My Routes are fine $routes->get('/', 'Home::index');

$routes->get('(:any)', 'Pages::view/$1');

Please help me in resolving this issue.. I may have more subfolders and then further subfolder. How can I resolve this issue..

I am trying to access the page as  https://mywebsite.com/views/mypage.php  but its giving error 404..

Comment: What's the path of the view you're trying to access?

Comment: Where's the logic for the `view` method in the `Pages` controller?

Comment: Do you have auto-routing enabled?